# imprimir tabela apartir de uma array de tamanho definido

Tags: javascript

```
<table border='1' id="tabela">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

gostaria de imprimir de forma diferente

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i =0;
    while(i< 100){
        var resto = i%10;

        if(i%10 == 0){
            $("tbody").append("<tr>"); 
        }
        $("tbody").append("<td>"+i+"</td>"); 
        i++;
        //document.getElementById("tabela").innerHtml += "<tr><td>"+i+"</tr></tr>"; 
        if(i%10 == 0){
            $("tbody").append("</tr>"); 
        } 
    }    
});
```

na verdade, eu queria imprimir dessa maneira:

[0][5][10][15][20]

[1][6][11][16][21]

[2][7][12][17][22]

[3][8][13][18][23]

[4][9][14][19][24]

como faço?

http://jsfiddle.net/8Lnmtusf/

Comment: Se alguma resposta te ajudou ou resolveu seu problema, dê um voto e marque como a resposta correta, caso contrário, informe mais detalhes sobre o que tentou e os resultados que obteve. Sempre votar e escolher as respostas corretas é uma boa prática e ajuda os outros usuários.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sou bom com JavaScript mas conseguir chegar a esta solução, tendo em mente sua afirmação de que a tabela tem um tamanho específico:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var linha = 0;
    var id = 0;
    var pos = 0;
    while(i < 100){
      if(linha < 10) {
        $("tbody").append("<tr id="+id+"></tr>");
        $("#"+id).append("<td>"+i+"</td>");
        linha++;
        id++;
      } else {
        if(pos==10) {
          pos = 0
        }
        $("#"+pos).append("<td>"+i+"</td>");
        pos++;
      }
      i++;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n5oc52uh/

Answer (score 0):

Use dois laços `for`. O primeiro `for` será para a iteração das linhas, e o segundo `for`, interno ao primeiro, fará a iteração das colunas.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // De acordo com a pergunta, o número de colunas da tabela é fixo ou pré determinado.
    var numeroDeColunas = 5;

    // O número de elementos do "array".
    var valorMaximo = 100;

    // Obtém o número de linhas.
    var numeroDeLinhas = valorMaximo / numeroDeColunas;

    // Esse laço faz a iteração das linhas.
    for (var i = 0; i < numeroDeLinhas; i++) {
        $("tbody").append("<tr id='linha"+ i +"'></tr>"); 

        // Faz a iteração das colunas.
        for (var j = 0; j < numeroDeColunas; j++) {
            $("#linha"+i).append("<td>"+ i + (5 * j) +"</td>");
        }
    }
});
```